# Command last in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

When the `last` command lists the entries, what is the default format at the duration?
For example: if I have an entry with a duration such as (03:43) does that mean that the user was logged on for 3 hours and 43 minutes?
And if there's an entry with a duration such as (3+02:56) does that mean that the user was logged on for 3 days 2 hours and 56 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, for every OS I've used, duration: (days+hours:minutes)

Check out this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200660)